# How to reduce use of Mage::getModel('catalog/category')

Tags: magento-1, getmodel

I'M NEW TO MAGENTO.

IN FILE 1.

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) 

$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'url'))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('is_topcategory', 1)
                    ->setPage(1, 5);
```

IN FILE 2.

```
$subcats = $category->getChildren();
$CatCustomFilter = array();

if ($subcats) {
    foreach (explode(',', $subcats) as $subCatid) {
        $subcatergory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
        $subsubcats = $subcatergory->getChildren();
        if ($subsubcats) {
            foreach (explode(',', $subsubcats) as $subsubCatid) {
                $_subCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subsubCatid);
                $CatCustomFilter[$subsubCatid] = $_subCategory->getCustomFilters();
            }
        } else {
            $CatCustomFilter[$subCatid] = $subcatergory->getCustomFilters();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in FILE 1 `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')` is called twice. 
And in FILE 2 `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')` called in foreach loop.

So is there anyway to reduce this code? Because I think it's totally bad practice to load the `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')` like above.

Also please provide me some guidance on how to work with `Mage::getModel()` properly so that we can't call it again and again.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use the `load()` method in the loop.

Magento provides a `getChildrenCategories()` method in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` class which in turn calls `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::getChildrenCategories()`.

So your file2 becomes something like:

```
$CatCustomFilter = array();
foreach ($category->getChildrenCategories() as $subcategory) {
    $subSubCategories = $subcategory->getChildrenCategories();
    if (count($subSubCategories)) {
        foreach ($subSubCategories as $subSubCategory) {
            $CatCustomFilter[$subSubCategory->getId()] = $subSubCategory->getCustomFilters();
        }
    } else {
        $CatCustomFilter[$subcategory->getId()] = $subcategory->getCustomFilters();
    }
}
```

as you can see, no load in the loops; the problem could be that `custom_filters` is a custom attribute of the `category` entity that wouldn't probably loaded; in that case you have to dig into the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::_getChildrenCategoriesBase()` method to see how to retrieve a category collection with custom attributes loaded.

> provide me some guidance on how to work with Mage::getModel() properly

as you already spotted out, the problem is not related to using the `Mage::getModel()` but to using load in loops which is considered a worst practice in general.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You are completely right. There are better ways to do this more efficiently. Models interact with the resourcemodel, that interact with the database. It is right to use the model for such goal, however Magento provides us with a couple of functions that make this a little more efficient. Refer to these functions:

- getChildren()
  returns a comma separated string of immediate children IDs
- getAllChildren()
  returns a string or array of all children IDs
- getChildrenCategories()
  returns a collection of immediate children categories

http://magecert.com/catalog.html

Also there is a design pattern that makes this usage of a models a bit more efficient. The Singleton design pattern makes sure there's only one instance. In above example you'll be spawning more than one instance, the singleton would be a good way too go while trying to implement one of above functions.

`<?php $category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session'); ?>`

http://magecert.com/basics.html

If needed, i would happily provide you with some examples. But i think these references are enough for you to understand or where to search for. These concepts are the things you should know.